# Run javascript dynamically before all existing javascript in page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that can modify/monkey-patch the Javascript environment in pages *before* any existing Javascript in the page runs.

I can do this for all pages by specifying a content_script in the manifest. However, I don't want to modify *all* pages, I only want to modify pages that have been loaded from the background script, i.e. from something like:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {
    url: url
});
```

---

In more detail, given a page

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>console.log('in page')</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and the content script, `content.js` for example,

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.text = 'console.log("injected from content script");'
scriptElement.async = false;
var parent = document.documentElement;
parent.insertBefore(scriptElement, parent.firstChild);
```

the console should output:

```
injected from content script
in page
```

This can be done for *all* pages, by having `"run_at": "document_start"` in the manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": [ "content.js"],
  "run_at": "document_start",
  "all_frames": true
}]
```

However, I would like this to only happen for pages loaded from the background script:

```
chrome.tabs.update(targetTabId, {
    url: url
});
```

How can this be done?

Comment: can your pages that are loaded from a background script be differentiated on the basis of their url at all? Just thinking of adding this to the 'matches' property in your manifest. Or in combo with exclude_matches

Comment: You can use declarativeContent API to register a content script dynamically and it'll be guaranteed to run before the page starts loading. Otherwise you can try chrome.tabs.executeScript with runAt:'document_start' right after updating the tab URL. Note, in both cases your added script element may (and often will) load after a page script so to avoid that, set script.text to a literal code string. It'll be harder to manage dev-wise, but that's the only reliable approach.

Comment: @monty Ah the urls can’t be known ahead of time alas

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried executeScript but I was having trouble getting it to run before all JavaScript, using using document_start (and calling it right after setting the url it didn’t seem to run at all). However, will have a look at the declarative API!

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm also having trouble getting RequestContentScript to work... no errors when creating the rule, but it the content script doesn't seem to get injected. Do you have any tips/suggestions?

Comment: Or of course feel free to post an answer with details!

Comment: @wOxxOm I have managed to get RequestContentScript injecting on Chrome Canary. However, the injected code runs _after_ the existing javascript in the pages, and it doesn't seem to support `runAt` to control this.

Comment: Sounds like you've used `css`.